# Issue with my Scrapy callback function

Tags: python-2.7, append, scrapy

I've been debugging this for quite a while and I'm not sure why, I cannot get the append method to work as I want. Now I'd like it to go to each player entry of a website (espn) I'm pulling data from, and store it in my players1 array. When I print(play) it shows me 15 different player entries but when I append them to the players1 array and then return it at the end of the loop, it only shows me the last (or first) player 15 times over.

```
def parseRoster(self, response):
    play = response.meta['play']
    players1 = []
    int = 0
    for players in response.xpath("//td[@class='sortcell']"):
        play['name'] = players.xpath("a/text()").extract()[0]
        play['position'] = players.xpath("following-sibling::td[1]").extract()[0]
        play['age'] = players.xpath("following-sibling::td[2]").extract()[0]
        play['height'] = players.xpath("following-sibling::td[3]").extract()[0]
        play['weight'] = players.xpath("following-sibling::td[4]").extract()[0]
        play['college'] = players.xpath("following-sibling::td[5]").extract()[0]
        play['salary'] = players.xpath("following-sibling::td[6]").extract()[0]
        print(play)
        players1.append(play)
    print(players1)
    return players1
```

If you guys want to see the rest of my code, just let me know and I'll upload it, I do have to make a request object & fill a meta method right after I declare the request object in my main code.

Edit: Also one of the reasons I'm not just extracted all data to 1 list (basically the reason for the [0] at the end of the extract) is because there's a lot of empty entries in the tables I'm pulling from and I feel like this way is just easier to send to my database.

Edit1: Okay so I put the print(players1) inside the for loop and am seeing that the loop is somehow overwriting the empty array with the latest player name. Now I'm not very sure why this is the case because I used it in the same way before and it did what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `play = response.meta['play']` references an `Item` instance that you create in a previous callback.

In the `for players in ...` loop, you're rewriting that same instance, and appending the same instance 15 times. You're building a list of 15 times the same Python object.

You need to copy this `play` instance from `response.meta` for each loop iteration, and then set the different fields. Something like this should work:

```
def parseRoster(self, response):
    play_original = response.meta['play']
    players1 = []
    int = 0
    for players in response.xpath("//td[@class='sortcell']"):

        play = play_original.copy()

        play['name'] = players.xpath("a/text()").extract()[0]
        play['position'] = players.xpath("following-sibling::td[1]").extract()[0]
        play['age'] = players.xpath("following-sibling::td[2]").extract()[0]
        play['height'] = players.xpath("following-sibling::td[3]").extract()[0]
        play['weight'] = players.xpath("following-sibling::td[4]").extract()[0]
        play['college'] = players.xpath("following-sibling::td[5]").extract()[0]
        play['salary'] = players.xpath("following-sibling::td[6]").extract()[0]
        print(play)
        players1.append(play)
    print(players1)
    return players1
```

Comment: I'm still confused on how the play_original.copy helps matters. I'm actually unsure where play_original even gets updated. To me the only time play is being updated is in the for loop.  
 
In my mind:  

- the play item is a temporary dictionary  
- play adds the set of name value pairs I'm scraping, to the end of the players1 array (aka list)  
- once it's scraped one players selector, it goes to the next and this next play item get appended to the players1 list  
  
I don't get how you saw that I was building a list of 15 instances.